# Exclude a dependency in jvm for release using gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build, build-tools

I am using a debugger library and I want to exclude it in my application when I create a release artifact
I know in android there is a Debug variant and I can use debugImplementation but how about JVM?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one condition (debug or not) the easiest to me seems to just use an if statement on a custom flag, eg like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-conditional-dependencies#configuring-conditional-dependency).

```
dependencies {
    if (project.hasProperty("debug")) {
        implementation("debugdep")
    }
}
```

`gradle -Pdebug`

Comment: but this way . I can't compile my classes for releases due to unresolved reference